# Electron using Accelerator to call a menu item in context menu

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, electron

How do I use the `accelerator` to call a `menu item` in context menu?

```
var menu = new Menu();

menu.append(new MenuItem({
  label: 'Say something',
  click: function(){
    alert("Hello");
  },
  accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+E"
}));


window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menu.popup(currentWindow);
}, false);
```

The above code works. The context menu appears and when the menu item is clicked the click callback works.

But the accelerator command doesn't work. Any ideas?

---

Side question:

can I pass the `click event` to `menu.popup` and then pass it to the `menu-item` `click` `callback`? Right now I am just storing the click event in a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Electron will register an accelerator unless you call `Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)` or equivalent. In your snippet you create a Menu but you aren't really doing anything with it until you call popup method. How would Electon know you want to use the accelerator before you register it? These are registered when they are set to the application menu.

That being said, it does not look like Electron provides an easy way register a local, renderer-process-only shortcut without creating a BrowserWindow menu. You can read more about it in this issue: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1334 To paraphrase, in OSX the accelerators are handled by the OS's menu system not by Electron, and so adding cross platform support for these localized shortcuts without the menu would require extensive work to the OSX version.

The solution suggested is to just capture the shortcuts you want in JavaScript and then trigger the command that way. You can still use the accelerator option to denote the key combination in the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the easiest way to register context menu accelerators today is by appending the context menu to your application menu, which will register them, but setting `visible: false` so they won't actually appear.

It's quite simple when using menu templates.

```
function registerAppMenu(app, invisibleMenus) {
  const template = [ ... ]; // use app to create the file-menu
  template.push(...invisibleMenus.map(menu => ({...menu, visible: false})));
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use this instead:

```
const {Menu} = require('electron').Menu;
const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu)
```

so you can use

```
mainMenuTemplate.push({
    /* your menu item properties*/
});`
```

to push it in the end. use the unshift() instead of push() to add to the beginning of the mainMenuTemplate, however even the accelerators are added and works as they should.